# Do stencil passes write to color buffer?

Tags: vulkan

I've been examining drawsubpasses sample in [LunarG's samples](https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanSamples) (file: API-Samples/drawsubpasses/drawsubpasses.cpp).

In this example, the active sub pass when the very first vkCmdDraw() is called, does not have a color attachment but only a depth/stencil attachment. The fragment shader used does have an output variable.

Reading the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/xhtml/vkspec.html#interfaces-fragmentoutput) didn't help me understand whether this usage is "safe", or how a driver would handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vulkan 1.0.16 seems to have corrected this. It explicitly says that no writes are performed to attachment indices greater than a subpasses `attachmentCount`, or which are explicitly declared `VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED`. The output variable will be undefined, but nothing will be written to it, based on the current subpass's description.

---

<strike>That is a very good question. I spent several minutes reading the spec in the expected places, and yet there is no language explaining what happens when a fragment shader writes to an output location that has no attachment in a subpass. It *ought* to be specified in section 14.3, but there is nothing there about this.</strike>

You may want to [file a Vulkan spec bug report.](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs)

I assume the correct behavior would be the same as OpenGL: to effectively ignore such outputs.

Comment: I guess it just gets ignored. Just like another [similar situation](https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanSamples/issues/79) i have noticed in the same example.

Comment: @hiddenbit: No, that one is clearly spelled out in the specification (unlike this particular issue). A pipeline which does not access descriptors is layout compatible with *any* descriptor set. And therefore has well-defined behavior with any descriptor set.